# How do i use multidimensional arraylist?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Hey guys ive read everything and i still cant get it. your my last hope.

All i need is a multidimensional arraylist that can store both a string and number at the same time. Please help.

Comment: No, use encapsulation.

Comment: Use a map or create a class. No such thing as multidimensional arraylist

Comment: Use List of a class , in that class you can create variables of string ,int etc..

Answer (score 2):

What are the information you want to store? What do they represent? I doubt you *just* want to store some number and some string without context. Find out what the context is, what they represent, then extract a class.

Is it a student's name and age?

```
class Student {
  private int age;
  private String name;
  public Student(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  ...
}
```

Is it a car manufacturer and production year?

```
class Car {
  private int productionYear;
  private String manufacturer;
  ...
}
```

Once you've extracted your class, you can just create an `ArrayList` of your type, something like this:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
cars.add(new Car("Toyota Avalon", 2014));
cars.add(new Car("Fiat Focus", 1982));
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be to have the list contain Object, and then check the type of objects after you pull them out.

There is almost certainly a better architecture though (separate lists, maybe using a map, maybe storing an object that itself contains both a number and a string) etc. Unfortunately you haven't given enough information to let us give any guidance on that...